# Different reasons for winforms closing event

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

How can I tell if the `closing()` event in my PowerShell winform app was raised because a **windows shutdown** was initiated?

I tried subscribing to systemevents `sessionEnding` and `sessionEnded` but the closing event occurs **before** they do.

I read somewhere that Windows sends a `WM_ENDSESSION` message to all applications when a shutdown/restart is initated. How can I query that inside my `on_closing` function (with PowerShell)?

Answer (score 1):

Got it: the `eventargs` of the `closing`-event actually contain a `closeReason`, which can be queried after the event has been fired. The value is usually `UserClosing` and in the case in question `WindowsShutDown`.

Links:

[Manage Event Subscriptions with Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/17/manage-event-subscriptions-with-powershell.aspx)

[MSDN: FormClosingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx)

[MSDN: CloseReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please link to the documentation or source for that information to help anyone coming across this same issue.

Comment: I normally would have done that in the first place, but by now I am hesitant on what to write here. Because every time somebody comes along and deletes, corrects, reformats and what not.

Comment: Usually MSDN links are great to use along with previous StackOverflow questions or answers that would help people landing here from searching find a path to the answer.